# How to remove square brackets and u char from json data

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I read a json file and get info formatted in this way

```
[{u'brand': [u'ABARTH']}, {u'brand': [u'ALFA ROMEO']} ...
```

I'm able to iterate over it doing every computation on the data but I'm not able to remove the u char and the square brackets when I iterate over the list to print out every elements

Do you know how can I do this?

This is the code I use

```
import json

data = json.loads(open('brands.json').read())

for item in data:
    print str(item['brand']).lower().replace(' ', '-')
```

Comment: What you have here is the representation of python dicts and lists. You cannot remove the brackets, because they exist only in the output. Show the code you have so far, to see what your problem is.

Comment: I updated the question showing the code

Comment: Please someone could tell me that down vote?every people who down vote without give an explanation is a stupid people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to "remove" anything. You have a dictionary, each of whose values is a *list*. Calling `str` on a list will show the repr of the elements in it. If you don't want that, print the *elements* of the list:

```
for item in data:
    print ', '.join(item['brand'])
```

Comment: Doing that the value are printed without u and square brackets

Answer (score 1):

Since the value for each`'brand'`key in each dictionary is a`list`object, you need to do index into it something like this -- which prints the first element in each of these lists:

```
data = [{u'brand': [u'ABARTH']},
        {u'brand': [u'ALFA ROMEO']},
        {u'brand': [u'FORD']}]

for item in data:
    print item['brand'][0].lower().replace(' ', '-')
```

Output:

```
abarth
alfa-romeo
ford
```